# Colours don't show up in seqrplot

Tags: r, traminer

I have a question regarding the seqrplot function in the R TraMineR package which plots sets of representative sequences. I have a big dataset on infringement proceedings with EU law (due to the length of the proceedings, I use the seqgranularity function) and use the following code.

```
library(TraMineR)
library(TraMineRextras)
library(grDevices)

#example data
directives <-
   structure(list(id = c(891L, 6826L, 9451L, 8816L), country_short = structure(c(2L,1L, 1L, 1L), 
.Label = c("I", "P"), class = "factor"), year = c(1992L, 1981L, 1980L, 1980L), 
federal = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), admin = c(5331L, 
1423L, 735L, 656L), pol = c(NA, NA, NA, 223L), adjud = c(NA, NA, NA, 330L), 
postlit = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), 
ADM = structure(c(2L, 1L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("(ADM,1423)", "(ADM,5331)", "(ADM,656)", 
"(ADM,735)"), class = "factor"), POL = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, 1L), .Label = "(POL,223)", 
class = "factor"), ADJ = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, 1L), .Label = "(ADJ,330)", 
class = "factor"), PLIT = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), 
.Label = character(0), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", "country_short", "year", "federal", 
"admin", "pol", "adjud", "postlit", "ADM", "POL", "ADJ", "PLIT"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")  

directives.seq<-seqdef(data=directives, var=9:12, xtstep=364, 
                       informat = "SPS", SPS.in=list(xfix="()",sdsep=","),
                       cpal=c("blue","gray","black","green"),
                       void="%", alphabet=c("ADM","POL","ADJ","PLIT"), 
                       labels=c("Administration phase","Political phase","Adjudication phase","Post-litigation phase"))
directives.seq.month<-seqgranularity(directives.seq, tspan=30, method="first")
directives.om<-seqdist(directives.seq.month, full.matrix=FALSE, method="OM", indel=1, sm="TRATE")
seqrplot(directives.seq.month, diss=directives.om, group=directives$federal, criterion="dist", nrep=3)
```

However, the plot does not seem to take into account the colour palette which is attributed to the sequence object. Instead it returns the representative sequences in black [(see screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5qXi.png). I checked my par() settings and they seem to be fine since all the other plots are duly coloured. Or is there any way of restoring the default setting of par()? I also tried to run the code with smaller subsamples but it didn't change the result. 
Does anybody have an idea how to solve this issue?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Please also add some example data to your question so that we can fully reproduce your problem and provide a solution that works for your data. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Oh yes sure, I will do that. Thank you!

Comment: I hope it works now!

Comment: I guess `directives <-` is missing in front of the `structure` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue probably arises because of the small boxes drawn around each observation. The solution is to use the `border=NA` argument. I illustrate using your data. However, with your `federal` group variable, one group has only one sequence while `seqrplot` requires at least two sequences by group. Therefore, I change the `federal` value for sequence 2.

```
directives$federal[2] <- 0
seqrplot(directives.seq.month, diss=directives.om, 
    group=directives$federal, criterion="dist", 
    nrep=2, border=NA)
```

and as you can see below, the colors show up as expected

[image]

Comment: Thank you Gilbert for taking the time. I also managed to make it work without the border=NA argument. There was a mistake in my long code; apparently, one has to reload the grDevices package after loading te TraMineRextras package (which I have omitted in my original code). Thank you very much anyway!

Comment: That sounds curious. `grDevices` is a base package that usually is automatically loaded when R is started. For me everything works fine without issuing `library(grDevices)`, neither before nor after loading `TraMineRextras`.